# Angular2 canReuse and onReuse not supported anymore

Tags: angular, routes, router, final

in Angular2 rc5 we used to route through one component with following router-config

```
{
       path:      '',
       component: MyComponent
   },
   {
       path:      ':view',
       component: MyComponent,
       data:      this.data
   },
   {
       path:      ':view/:childview',
       component: MyComponent,
       data:      this.data
   },
   {
       path:      ':view/:childview/:subchildview',
       component: MyComponent,
       data:      this.data
   }
```

now in Angular2 final version this isn't possible anymore because the interfaces CanReuse and OnReuse disappeared.

Now i have the problem switching between different paths.

When i am at a path like

start/startpage

i'm getting to it, but if i route to

start/startpage/info

the component is used to be initialized again and not reusing it...

What can i do to change it?

Thanks

Comment: this is not very useful @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39762485/want-to-prevent-component-recreation-while-routing-in-angular-2/39763254?noredirect=1#comment66822070_39763254