# Want to prevent Component recreation while routing in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

Let's say we have two routes `Dashboard` and `Profile`. `Dashboard` has dynamic tabs feature like `Google spreadsheet`. I want to do some interactions(build charts, visualizing some data) creating tabs in the `Dashboard`. Now, if I route to `Profile` and then route back to `Dashboard`, I want to see what was before in those tabs in `Dashboard`. It means, I want to maintain the state in the client side. AFAIK while routing between components, it recreates components. Is it possible to make spreadsheet like application while using angular 2 routing? I need to use routing because in my application I have to use LazyLoading feature.

So what should be the idea? I am new to angular 2.

Comment: I think it's possible from routing. I've read this blog, but haven't myself tried to implement such advanced routing you seek. https://vsavkin.com/angular-2-router-d9e30599f9ea#.2o8b488po

Comment: I read the blog and also the new book of vsavkin. But it's way too complicated for me to  understand the concept. That's why I am seeking a better and easier understanding :/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently components are reused **only** when only route parameters change while staying on the same route.

If the route is changed, event when the new route adds the same component, the component is recreated.

The preferred workaround is to keep the model in a shared service that stays alive during route changes and use the data from this service to restore the previous state of the component.

It was mentioned that there are plans to support custom reuse strategies with the router but no timeline when this will become available.

**Update**

Support for custom reuse strategy was added to Angular2.

See also

- https://www.softwarearchitekt.at/post/2016/12/02/sticky-routes-in-angular-2-3-with-routereusestrategy.aspx
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846
- [Angular2 router 2.0.0 not reloading components when same url loaded with different parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533291/angular2-router-2-0-0-not-reloading-components-when-same-url-loaded-with-differe/39533351#39533351)

Comment: But as per my requirements, I need to create multiple tabs under `Dashboard`(it might be even 100 tabs like google spreadsheet).So what should I do? Can you shine some light on `RouterState`?

Comment: I don't think `RouterState` is related. You might want to look aux-routes and don't navigate away from the current route to show `Profile` but instead show it as a modal or similar. Aux routes support still seemed a bit limited to me (didn't experiment too much yet with them though).

Comment: I mentioned `Profile` as an example :/ but my application is like, build interactions in the tab like google spreadsheet and store those tabs in `Dashboard`. And I need LazyLoading. My requirement is complex one and I am having problems with the initial architecture :(

Comment: You might ignore that limitation for now and hope the Angular team will provide a solution eventually like mentioned in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7757#issuecomment-236737846

Comment: You can also replace the `<router-outlet>` component with a custom one, that doesn't remove specific components, but only hides them instead.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/0614c8c99d6680c3db3fac012ed45ff5c49b5a59/modules/%40angular/router/src/directives/router_outlet.ts isn't very complex.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the example provided by @Günter Zöchbauer, for my own understanding I decided to distill a minimal example.

[See it in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gc9vmw)

**In Summary:**

First I implemented a [RouteReuseStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/RouteReuseStrategy):

```
export class CustomReuseStrategy implements RouteReuseStrategy {

    handlers: {[key: string]: DetachedRouteHandle} = {};

    calcKey(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
        let next = route;
        let url = '';
        while(next) {
            if (next.url) {
                url = next.url.join('/');
            }
            next = next.firstChild;
        }
        return url;
    }

    shouldDetach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    store(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, handle: DetachedRouteHandle): void {
        this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)] = handle;
    }

    shouldAttach(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return !!route.routeConfig && !!this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)];
    }

    retrieve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): DetachedRouteHandle {
        if (!route.routeConfig) { return null; }
        return this.handlers[this.calcKey(route)];
    }

    shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
        return this.calcKey(curr) === this.calcKey(future);
    }
}
```

Within my `AppModule`, I added a new provider and configured some routes:

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'one',
    component: OneComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'two',
    component: TwoComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [... RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)...]
  providers: [...{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: CustomReuseStrategy }...],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Finally, I defined some components as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <a [routerLink]="['/one']" >Route One</a><br>
    <a [routerLink]="['/two']" >Route Two</a><br>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-one',
  template: `
  Route One currently showing<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter some text">
  `,
})
export class OneComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-two',
  template: `
  Route Two currently showing<br>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter some text">
  `,
})
export class TwoComponent {}
```