# How to reload data from backend without refreshing the window?

Tags: angular

I've defined a route `foo/:id/edit` to use few resolvers that make service calls.

After some action on this view I want to reload data gathered from those resolvers without refreshing the whole page.

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41804864/how-to-trigger-route-resolver-manually) I shouldn't call resolvers manually. But maybe there's another way.

Comment: Would you consider injecting a SharedService in the component that gets loaded on path `foo/:id/edit` and then use that service to get the data recurringly as opposed to using Resolvers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was navigating to the same URL I'm on:

`this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);`

but in order to trigger the resolvers `runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'` had to be added to route config and `onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'` to `app-routing.module`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            [
            { useHash: true, enableTracing: DEBUG_INFO_ENABLED, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled' }
        )
    ],
```

What is worth noticing is `scrollPositionRestoration: 'disabled'` which keeps my scroll position intact. I've read that it's available since Angular 6.1.

Instead of adding those configs above you can add `refresh=1` or similar to your URL so the resolvers would get triggered out of the box.

Inspired by [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48280010/1873995).